# Using Bash to split XML data into variables

Tags: scripting, variable, curl, xml, xmllint

I am trying to download some files from a services. The files are found in an XML file. The XML file can have a single file or several files to download. However, now I have a problem with my  script. I do not know how to split string from XMLLINT into array so that I can download each file individually.

I need to split the string into several variables and then download each file of the URL string.

However the file 201701_1 do not repeat and hence, I download them using curl without any problems. But the files coverage.zip repeat and they become overwritten by curl.
I do:
Then I do curl to download individual files.

```
curl -O -b cookie $URL
```

At the moment, my script is as follows:

```
while read edition; do   XML="<?xml version=\"1.0\"
encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <download-area>   <files>
    <file>
      <url>https://google.com/411/201701_01_01.zip</url>
    </file>
    <file>
      <url>https://google.com/411/201701_01_02.zip</url>
    </file>   </files> </download-area>
    "
    URL=$(echo $XML | xmllint --xpath \
    "/*[name()='download-area']/*[name()='files']/*[name()='file']/*[name()='url']/text()" -)

    echo "URL:: " $URL

done < $LATEST_EDITION
```

LATEST_EDITION is a simply a file with lines.

My question is::
How can I split VAR_1 and VAR_2 into several URLs so that I can download them individually?
How can I prevent coverage.zip from being overwritten?

Comment: You can use `https://` as a delimiter for splitting, but iit would be smarter not to join them in the first place. Have you tried to make  `xmllint` produce output with delimiters between the URLs?

Comment: your current script does not use any `VAR_1` and `VAR_2`. Update your question

Comment: I have removed VAR_1 and VAR_2 which brought confusion to the question.

Comment: You might want to include an example of the XML data that you're trying to parse and what the expected output/result would be for that example.

Answer (score 4):

`xmllint` is pretty useless to extract information from XML documents. You may want to consider `xmlstarlet` or `xml_grep` (from `perl`'s XML::Twig) or `xml2`.

With `xmllint`, you could still extract one string at a time with:

```
VAR1=$(printf '%s\n' "$XML" |
  xmllint --xpath '/download-area/files/file[1]/url/text()' -)
VAR2=$(printf '%s\n' "$XML" |
  xmllint --xpath '/download-area/files/file[2]/url/text()' -)
```

For values like here not containing newline characters, you can use `bash`'s `readarray` as:

```
readarray -t var < <(
  xmlstarlet sel -t -v /download-area/files/file/url  <<< "$XML")
```

Or

```
readarray -t var < <(
  xml2 <<< "$XML" | sed -n 's|^/download-area/files/file/url=||p')
```

Or:

```
readarray -t var < <(
  xml_grep --text_only /download-area/files/file/url <<< "$URL")
```

Comment: Huh?  `xmllint` is an excellent utility for extracting information from a structured document using the XPath expression language.  Where it "fails" is that it does not produce the output in a format that people can easily use with procedural languages such as Bash

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
declate -a url_array
url_array=(`echo $XML | grep -o "http.*zip" | tr '\n' ' '`)
```

Comment: Why translate the `\n` to `' '`? Both space and newline are in the default value of `$IFS`. It would make more sense to remove space from `$IFS`. Also, when using the split+glob operator, it's good practice to disable the glob part when you don't need it. It makes little sense to invoke split+glob upon the expansion of `$XML`, so that `$XML` should be quoted.

Comment: 1st line should be "declare" command, not "declate" (it is misspelled). I can't change it b/c it's < 6 characters that need to be corrected. Silly limitation of StackExchange.

Answer (score 1):

`xmllint` isn't a great tool for slicing and dicing XML. To solve your two problems (parsing XML, and ensuring unique URLs, I think?) in a robust way using `bash` and `xmlstarlet`:

```
#!/bin/bash
XML='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<download-area>
  <files>
    <file>
      <url>https://google.com/411/201701_01_01.zip</url>
    </file>
    <file>
      <url>https://google.com/411/201701_01_02.zip</url>
    </file>
  </files>
</download-area>'

# IFS=$'\n'   ## required if URLs contains spaces
urls=( $(xml select -t -m  "/download-area/files/file" -v url -nl  <<< $XML ) )

declare -A unique  # associative array
for uu in ${urls[*]}; do let unique[$uu]++; done

for uu in "${!unique[@]}"; do
  printf "URL is %s\n" ${uu}
done
```

This uses `xmlstarlet` in `select` mode, with a template (`-t`) which matches (`-m`) an xpath from which it selects the value (`-v`) of the `url` node and adds a newline (`-nl`) after each one. (xmlstarlet is even more flexible than this, you can use `-v` multiple times and `-o` to add arbitrary text wherever required.)

This also uses the `<<<` redirection which saves an `echo`/pipe.

The URLs are stored in a normal indexed array `urls`. Next, loop over the array to store the URLs as the keys in an *associative array* — this solves the uniqueness problem (and the count of occurrences is kept as the value for each entry).

If you're not familiar with bash's associative arrays the second loop needs some additional explanation. The expression `"${unique[@]}"` expands all the *values* of an array, this uses `"${!unique[@]}"` which instead expands all the *indexes* of an array, this should make sense if you dump the array data with `declare -p unique`:

```
declare -A unique=([https://google.com/411/201701_01_01.zip]="1" 
                   [https://google.com/411/201701_01_02.zip]="1" )
```

You can even do this all in one loop, though it's a little harder to understand perhaps:

```
while read line; do
  [[ -n "$line" ]] && let unique[$line]++ 
done < <(xml sel -t -m  "/download-area/files/file" -v url  -nl <<< $XML)
```

XMLstarlet may be installed as either `xml` or `xmlstarlet`

Comment: Thanks for this.. I just managed to put an almost similar implementation..
I also learned that XMLLINT is not the best tool for slicing and dicing with XML.. Kudos..!!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using `sed`to parse the output from `xmllint`.  Note the shortened XPath expression!

```
URL=$( echo $XML | xmllint --xpath "//url" - | sed -e 's/<url>//g' -e 's/<\/url>/\n/g' )

printf "%s\n" "$URL"
```

This will output the URLs one per line